# Skip empty cells from datagrid when saving to database

Tags: c#, datagrid

I have a datagrid with 8 columns, the first 6 columns are filled from a SQL table and last 2 will be filled by the user and saved into another table, the user will input numeric data (double); how can I save the two columns data at once skipping the cells that the user leaves black.
 at the moment I am able to save the data to database but it requires all cells to have data or at least a zero in it. I am using the following code:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = Conexion.Conectado()) 
    for (int i = 0; i < Dgv_registro_pagos.Rows.Count - 0; i++)
       {

       String GuardarBD = "Insert into Registro_pagos (Monto_pago, fk_prestamo_id, Mora, fecha_pago) Values (@Monto_pago, @fk_prestamo_id, @Mora, @fecha_pago) ";

       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(GuardarBD, conn);

       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;


       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fk_prestamo_id", Dgv_registro_pagos.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Monto_pago", Dgv_registro_pagos.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mora", Dgv_registro_pagos.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha_pago", DateTime.Now);


       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

       conn.Close();
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = Conexion.Conectado())
            for (int i = 0; i < Dgv_registro_pagos.Rows.Count - 0; i++)
            {
                if (Dgv_registro_pagos.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value != null &&
                     Dgv_registro_pagos.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value != null)
                {
                    String GuardarBD = "Insert into Registro_pagos (Monto_pago, fk_prestamo_id, Mora, fecha_pago) Values (@Monto_pago, @fk_prestamo_id, @Mora, @fecha_pago) ";

                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(GuardarBD, conn);

                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;


                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fk_prestamo_id", Dgv_registro_pagos.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Monto_pago", Dgv_registro_pagos.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mora", Dgv_registro_pagos.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha_pago", DateTime.Now);


                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: I get the following error: "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'"

Comment: I couldn't remember if empty cells are space or null - try the updated version above

Comment: same result using null

Comment: Can you single step the code to determine that the "if" statement is causing the exception?  It's hard to debug without seeing it run.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5E983k23FC6MWxnWWxhOXlOWUk here you can take a look, Thank btw

Comment: I see the problem - you didnt take off the .ToString()

Comment: You are right! I over look it, Thanks that solve my problem